# "Not null violation: 7" when using manyToOne and oneToMany relations on Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a very basic schema like this:

**Comments.yml:**

```
manyToOne:
  pages:
    targetEntity: Pages
    inversedBy: comments
    joinColumn:
      name: page_id
      referencedColumnName: idx

... other things ...
```

**Pages.yml:**

```
oneToMany:
  comments:
    targetEntity: Comments
    mappedBy: pages
    cascade: ["persist"] // i added this later but has no effect for both persist and merge.
    orderBy:
      idx: desc

... other things ...
```

Now, everything is working just fine. I  can get `Pages` from `Comments` and **reverse**. The problem is, when i try to insert a **new** row to the database, it says `page_id` is `null`.

**Example:**

```
$comment = new Comments();
$comment->setPageId(2); // it is "2"
$comment->setText($textData);

$this->_em->persist($comment);
$this->_em->flush($comment);
```

Now the result is false. It throws an exception and says `SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "page_id" violates not-null constraint`.

Well, **if i remove the oneToMany and ManyToOne relations, it works!** If i use them it says it is null even if i give it...

Where is my mistake? Any help or idea is appreciated!

**EDIT**:

I found this method: `getReference()`

```
$item = $em->getReference('MyProject\Model\Item', $itemId);
$cart->setPage($item);
```

Now it is **working** but i do not know if this is the correct way. Please inlight me.

Basically, i want to **add** a comment **without** modifying (not remove nor update) the page table. But, i want to fetch them together as ManyToOne and OneToMany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You want to add a page to the Comments entity You should call a method like `$comment->setPage($page)` this method is automatically generated if you use the `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities` command line. The $page object should be the $page object loaded from the database. e.g.

```
$page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Pages')->findOneBy(array('id' => $pageId));

$comment = new Comments();
$comment->setPage($page);
$comment->setText($textData);

$this->_em->persist($comment);
$this->_em->flush();
```

If this doesn't help You, please post your code from your controller and the pages and comments entity.

Comment: My code is exactly same as your answer. I am at that point. Instead of `findOneBy()` i used `getReference()`. Because if i use `findOneBy()` method, it fetch from database and then re insert it. This is **critical**... What if changes are made in the background while this process the comment? So, i have to insert comment without modifying or grabbing the page table... _Also **Example** from my question is from my `Controller`..._ Basically, i dont want to add Page. I want to add only a comment to the comments table which is page_id = 2... But doctrine forces me to pass the whole page entity.

Comment: xangr:  Your code was not the same as presented.  Doctrine works with an object map.  You are thinking too literally about the way the keys related the underlying tables.  Doctrine should manage that for you.  Notice that @Krypthonite gets a $page "entity" and calls setPage() passing that.  getReference is an alternative to passing an actual object, when you typically don't have the object available.  Whether or not it is best to use the reference or $obj = findOneBy() depends on what else you might be doing with $page in your code.  The queries it will do will probably be equivalent here.

Comment: @xangr Doctrine only modifies your Pages entity, when you call some setter on it. In the code i posted the Pages entity is not modified at all.

Comment: @Krypthonite So, you are saying this: When a new comment is added; setPage($pageEntity) only used for getting the "foreign key" but it is not modified or updated. If this is the case then your solution is correct.

Comment: @xangr This is exactly what I meant :)